# How to pass a gradient through a categorical distribution?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, gradient-descent, backpropagation

I have a sequence of words:

```
my_sequence = "This is my sequence"
```

I also have `model_1` that predicts a label for each word, out of 2 possible labels:

```
model_1_probabilities_predictions = [[0.1, 0.9], [0.4, 0.6], [0.7, 0.3], [0.9, 0.1]]
```

So far so good. Now here is where I'm stuck:

I have another model, call it `model_2`. This model needs to take the categorical predictions (i.e., the `argmax` of `model_1_probabilities_predictions`) in order to make a prediction. It only uses the words corresponding to the first label.

```
model_2_predictions = model_2( [This, is] )
```

Using this I can get a loss:

```
loss = loss_function(model_2_predictions, true_label)
```

There are 3 issues:

```
1. I can't differentiate through argmax

2. Even if there was a way to differentiate through argmax, the loss is 0 if the categorical labels are not exact and 1 otherwise (e.g., 0 for [label_1, label_1, label_0, label_0] but 1 for [label_0, label_1, label_0, label_0]).

3. Since model_2 only uses the words corresponding to the first label, the loss can't really propagate to the other words
```

I looked into the [Gumbel softmax trick](https://neptune.ai/blog/gumbel-softmax-loss-function-guide-how-to-implement-it-in-pytorch) but it's not quite what I need, as `model_2` must have the categorical labels, so there isn't really a way around it

Comment: Your question is quite confusing, what is `true_label`, and why are the inputs to `model_2` `[this, is]`. I thought the output of `argmax(model_1_probabilities_predictions)` were a sequence of labels (of which there are two classes).

Comment: `model_2` is a LM that takes an input of a string. `true_label` is 0-4, corresponding to a multiple choice answers. And yes, the `argmax` is as you described and the model only uses the words corresponding to the first label. Is anything else confusing? I appreciate the help!